# Is there a way to name an object based on the value of an integer? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uibutton

I'm trying to run a for loop and every time a loop runs through a UIButton is allocated and initialized. The issue is that all of these buttons need different names. Is there a way to name the button based on the value of the integer in the for loop?

Comment: Show some relevant code and better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is sounds like you want to put the buttons in an [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/). Items in the array can be referenced by an index into the array.

Comment: Will they get messed up if they're all the same name though?